# Creating a function to use in getJSON callback

Tags: jquery, function, getjson

I want a function that I can use in different getJSON calls, but I get a data not defined error

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function populateCalendarMonth(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}
var d = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);
var args = {
        "action": "church_admin",
        "method": "calendar-render",
        "date": d
    };

$.getJSON(ajaxurl,args,populateCalendarMonth(data))

});
```

Doesn't work, but

```
$.getJSON(ajaxurl,args,function(data){console.log(data)});
```

Shows my JSON data beautifully in the console.

How do I create a function that can be used again? (eventually the calendar will be populated on page load with this month and other months on clicking next and previous!)

Comment: `$.getJSON(ajaxurl,args,populateCalendarMonth(data))` doesn't make much sense. You're calling the function with... `data`, which isn't defined. You probably want to just *not* call the function.

Comment: So function(data){} works as a callback but myFunction(data) doesn't. So how do i do it then?

Comment: with `myFunction`. Because you've already defined `myFunction`, there's no need to specify the paramlist or content of the function. (in your current setup, you're actually executing (or calling) `myFunction` before you've even executed the ajax method.)

Comment: Goodness, how simple is that! $.getJSON(ajaxurl,args,populateCalendarMonth) does the job. So a callback function that is predefined doesn't need the params (I'm such a PHP guy!) Not sure of the procedure here as this is comments rather than an answer and why do I have -1 on a question?

Comment: You have the solution, but not the reason.  If you write `var f = func()` it calls that function and returns the value.  If you write `var f = func` is assigns the function to f.  In the callback case you want to assign the function, not call it at the time of assignment, so `$.getJSON(url,args, func)` says pass `func` to the callback, while `$.getJSON(url,args, func())` says call func and returns its value to the callback.  In the case an inline function, it's `$.getJSON(url,args, function() {} )` vs `$.getJSON(url,args, (function() {})() )`

Comment: Thank you so much guys, @freedomn-m your comment has helped a lot in understanding how it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add parameter to your call, as that's passed by the callback by itself.

```
$.getJSON(ajaxurl, args, populateCalendarMonth)
```